# Variable inside of read.csv explicit path string

Tags: r

**Problem:**

How can you insert a variable into explicit directory path, which is nested inside of a read.csv function? Attempting cat and sprintf have not worked, possibly because the function is nested.

**R Code:**

```
    mainDir <- "C:/Users/"
    subDir <- "G"

    if (file.exists(subDir)) {
        userName <- "John"
    } else {
        userName <- "Mike"
    }

    sampleData <- read.csv("C:/Users/", userName, "/Google Drive/data/sampleData.csv")
```

Comment: You need `paste()` as in `read.csv(paste0("string1", userName, "string2"))`

Comment: `paste("C:/Users/", userName, "/Google Drive/data/sampleData.csv", sep='')` Be sure to make the `sep` be the empty string; hence the two single quotes together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the recommendations of of @Dan Y and @Edward Carney above:

```
pathStart <- "C:/Users/"

if (file.exists("C:/Users/John")) {
    pathMiddle <- "John"
} else {
    pathMiddle <- "Mike"
}

pathEnd <- "/Google Drive/data/sampleData.csv"

sampleData <- read.csv(paste0(pathStart, pathMiddle, pathEnd, sep=''))
```